# How to avoid record duplication

Tags: c#

If I try to submit the Employee into the database whose **email address** already exists in the database, I want to throw the Message box to let the user know of the issue, otherwise let the data be saved.

Down below is my current code.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using System.Data.SqlClient;

namespace Employees
{
    public partial class Registration : Form
    {
        SqlConnection con;
        SqlCommand com;
        SqlDataReader sdr;
        string cmdstr;

        string constr = @"Data Source=DESKTOP-J6KRI77\SQLEXPRESS; Initial Catalog = SELLnBUY; Integrated Security=true";


        public Registration()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
        }

 private void btnsubmit_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            con = new SqlConnection(constr);
            cmdstr = "INSERT INTO Emptbl([First Name], [Last Name], sex, [Birth Date], Email, Password, Confirm_Password, Membership) VALUES(@fname, @lname, @sex, @dob, @email, @password, @confirmpassword, @membership)";

            con.Open();
            com = new SqlCommand(cmdstr, con);

            if (txtfname.Text == "" || txtlname.Text == "" || combosex.SelectedItem.ToString() == "" || maskeddob.Text == "" || txtemail.Text == "" || txtpassword.Text == "" || txtconfirmpassword.Text == "" || (!radiopremium.Checked && !radioregular.Checked))
            {
                MessageBox.Show("Please, fill all the fields");
            }

            else
            {
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@fname", txtfname.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@lname", txtlname.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@sex", combosex.SelectedItem.ToString());
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dob", maskeddob.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtemail.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@password", txtpassword.Text);
                com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@confirmpassword", txtconfirmpassword.Text);
                if (radiopremium.Checked)
                {
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@membership", "Premium");
                }
                else
                {
                    com.Parameters.AddWithValue("@membership", "Regular");
                }
                com.ExecuteNonQuery();

                MessageBox.Show("Thanks for registering");
                txtfname.Clear();
                txtlname.Clear();
                combosex.Text = "";
                maskeddob.Clear();
                txtemail.Clear();
                txtpassword.Clear();
                txtconfirmpassword.Clear();
                grpbxmembership.Text = "";

                txtfname.Focus();

            }
con.Close();
}
```

Comment: It seems that you want to UPDATE the record if the email exists. What if the email doesn't exist?

Comment: @Blorgbeard, Actually I want to avoid duplicates in my database.So If for some reasons I register an employee who has been registered already, by the found email address in the database then I want to throw a warning for that, if the email doesn't exist then I have no problem with that as I can write the code to insert that particular record.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your code is very old. All people use ORMs nowadays.

Then, about your question, you just need to check DB for the same data before you insert it.

```
SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("select count(*) from Emptbl where  Email= @email");
  command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email", txtemail.Text);
  var count= (Int32)cmd.ExecuteScalar();
   if(count>0) 
       //Show error
```

Comment: Hahahaaa... @AshkanSirous You know I'm trying to learn this C# on my own. So maybe, my sources of knowledge are very old too. Back to your help, Your code makes a lot of sense to me even though I'm running late to try it right now but will do it tomorrow morning and get back to you on whatever the case.

Comment: @Moni sure :D test this one and then if you want to learn how to code easily with C#, take a look at this link:
https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/jj193542.aspx

(  Entity framework with code first)

Comment: would you mind to rewrite this whole code of my project the way it's supposed? Because, when I tried to incorporate that piece of code in to my codes, I ended up getting an error stating:  "Execute Scalar: Connection property has not been initialized" So, I went on and tried to incorporate the con.Open() and con.Close() by using both one at a time; if... else... and try... catch...finally without any luck. Thanks in advance

Comment: Oooh!! I've figured out your SqlCommand property  was missing missing the connection parameter right at the end. And I've been getting an error since I just cut and pasted it in my code.But right now it's working like a charm!! Thanks so much. I'll go through that link to get my codding better

Comment: By the way, don't forget to mark my post as the correct answer, and to vote for it☺